# how embed flash video in google desktop gadget?

Tags: flash, google-gadget, streaming-flv-video, google-desktop

I have a requirement where I need to create a Google desktop gadget which can play flash videos from a given video URL.  For example, if I give `"http://www.example.com/xyz.flv"` then the gadget should play that video.

Please provide some sample code if anybody has worked on this kind a widget.

Answer (score 0):

check out this article:

- **[Details Views and YouTube Videos in Desktop Gadgets](http://code.google.com/apis/desktop/articles/e12.html)**

It contains information and code samples for embedding youtube videos into google desktop gadgets.

EDIT: if you only have the .flv file, you will need to create a flash player, see this question for some discussion:

- [Video player (flow player or jw), which one is best for growing site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595846/video-player-flow-player-or-jw-which-one-is-best-for-growing-site)